# HTML spacing if value is empty

Tags: html, css, string, html-table

I'm having difficulties in formatting my HTML page.

As you can see from the source code, it's a table where each row contains a formatted list of records dynamically populated by my web app.
In the case one of the columns has an empty value, I would like to keep the formatting of the lines, so I should basically add enough spaces or think about an HTML block with the exact size of the text value.

The nice thing is each value has a fixed character length, so it should come in advantage.
I thought about creating a span but it doesn't support the width attribute and I should change the style to `display:block`, but in my opinion, it's getting a little too tricky, as I would like a simple and clever solution.
I attach the source code of the page and the output I get at the moment.

[image: Output]

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"></head>
    <body>
    <table>
    <tr><td style="font-size: 11px; color: #000000; font-family: Verdana; border-bottom: #ff0000 1px solid;">
    <table>
    <tr><td>test1:</td></tr>
    <tr><td>
    <ul>
    <li>FIELD1:;, FIELD2: <b>443</b>, FIELD3: <b>191,51</b></li>
    <li>FIELD1: <b>1000101</b>, FIELD2: <b>442</b>, FIELD3: <b>43,2</b></li><li>FIELD1: <b>1000176</b>, FIELD2:, FIELD3: <b>36</b></li>
    </ul></td></tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying: "each value has fixed length"? Is it fixed number of characters, or fixed width? Also, I don't think setting span's display to inline-block is a tricky hack. Depending on what you're trying to achieve here, It can help you out

Comment: Each value has a fixed char length, I'll edit the question to explain it better.

Comment: Firstly, the table syntax is wrong! A table should be properly formatted with `<thead>` and `<tbody>`.  then if a row has an empty value, the width/spacing will still be the same across the table. Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ddx3Lsbw/1/)

Comment: Yes - That was my next question - do you have to use unordered list inside of table cell? Can  you not insert these "field" + "value" fields into td seperately?

Comment: Of course you can. Change your code so that your `<ul> becomes <tr>` and `<li> becomes <td>` and place it in `<tbody>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you got your semantics messed up. You try to build a table but then you put the whole table content in 1 cell and then you try to emulate the table in there by using a list.

Just put 1 field in 1 table cell and and it will come together quite easily. Also: "test1" is in this context the table caption or maybe a headline.

The first variant assumes that the field names might vary from row to row. If that is not the case they belong into the table header instead.

```css
table#test1 tbody tr th {
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: left;
}
table#test1 tbody tr td {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
}

table#test2 thead tr td {
  font-weight: bold;
}
table#test2 tbody tr td {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="test1">
      <caption>test1</caption>
      <tbody>
        <tr><th>FIELD1:</th><td></td><th>FIELD2:</th><td>443</td><th>FIELD3:</th><td class="value">191,51</tr>
        <tr><th>FIELD1:</th><td class="value">1000101</td><th>FIELD2:</th><td class="value">442</td><th>FIELD3:</th><td class="value">43,2</tr>
        <tr><th>FIELD1:</th><td class="value">1000176</td><th>FIELD2:</th><td class="value"></td><th>FIELD3:</th><td class="value">36</tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table id="test2">
      <caption>test2</caption>
      <thead>
        <tr><td>FIELD1</td><td>FIELD2</td><td>FIELD3</tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr><td></td><td>443</td><td>191,51</tr>
        <tr><td>1000101</td><td>442</td><td>43,2</tr>
        <tr><td>1000176</td><td></td><td>36</tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```